# Crystal Lang Websocket server

Tags: websocket, crystal-lang

I need help with Crystal Lang websockets, I want to know how to upgrade my connection on websocket. I want make simple websocket server

Answer (score 1):

hope this help

```
require "http/server"
SOCKETS = [] of HTTP::WebSocket
ws_handler = HTTP::WebSocketHandler.new do |socket|
puts "Socket opened"
  SOCKETS << socket
socket.on_message do |message|
    SOCKETS.each { |socket| socket.send "Echo back from server: #{message}" }
  end
socket.on_close do
    puts "Socket closed"
  end
end
server = HTTP::Server.new([ws_handler])
address = server.bind_tcp "0.0.0.0", 3000
puts "Listening on http://#{address}"
server.listen
```

https://medium.com/@muhammadtriwibowo/simple-websocket-using-crystal-13b6f67eba61

Comment: Thank you so much I was getting error but I fix it with this change 
```
socket.on_close do
    puts "Socket closed"
    SOCKETS.delete(socket)
  end
```
Just problem is because connection instantly close

Answer (score -3):

if you are looking for ready to use something, then you can use Shivneri framework created by me - which provides a javascript library and MVC based approach to create a socket server.

### How to create a web socket end point

```
class ChatController < Shivneri::WebSocketController

    @[On("message")]
    def receive_message(data : String)

        # send message to caller
        clients.current.emit("message", "Received message is #{data}")

         # send message to all clients
        clients.emit("message", "Someone sent message #{data}")
    end

end
```

### How to connect to web socket end point using javascript

Shivneri framework provides a javascript library [shivneri-ws-client-javascript](https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/shivneri-ws-client-javascript) to help you create a real time web application

```
var socket = new shivneriWsClient.Instance();
socket.on("message", function(data){
    console.log("data", data);
});

await socket.init(`<web-socket-url>`);

// emit event to server
socket.emit("message","Successfully connected")
```

It provides many functionalities like grouping of clients, events when client is connected & disconnected etc.

For more information, take a look at shivneri websocket doc - https://shivneriforcrystal.com/tutorial/websocket/